# Website Not Available After Configuring HTTPS Binding

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, https

I'm trying to configure HTTPS on my local IIS server (Windows 7 Pro). I can hit http://localhost just fine when no HTTPS binding is defined, however once I add it, I get a 404 error. Also, when I add the HTTPS binding and try to restart the server through the IIS Manager, I get an exception (image below). I have no idea where to begin to troubleshoot and haven't found anything applicable through Google.

Below are some images of what I'm seeing when configuring the binding.

I've created a self-signed certificate to use for the binding:
[image]

When I go to edit the bindings, only a default HTTP binding is present:
[image]

I proceed to create the binding:
[image]

At this point, if I navigate to https://localhost, I get a 404 error. If I try and restart the server, I get met with an exception:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the VMWare Workstation Service was interfering with port 443. After stopping the service I could successfully get HTTPS working on my local IIS.